# How can I use endpoint DSL for a custom component in Apache Camel?

Tags: maven, apache-camel

I just developed a custom component to wrap and add some functionalities to the standard mail component.

The component by itself works fine when creating the endpoint using a URI, but I would like to have the possibility to create the endpoint using the endpoint DSL.

I would like to pass from `.to("mysmtp:hostname?port=25&to=<mail@domain.com>")` to `.to(mysmtp("hostname").port(25).to("<mail@domain.com>")`

To write my component I started from the project generated from the Maven archetype `camel-archetype-component` and, as advised [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/writing-components.html), I checked that the Camel Component Maven Plugin is included in my POM.

Looking at the official Camel [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/Endpoint-dsl.html#_the_fluent_dsl_now_provides_type_safety_for_parameters) it seems the code for the endpoint DSL should be auto-generated starting from the meta-model extracted from the component code, and this seems to be confirmed by the fact that, for instance, the `MailEndpointBuilderFactory` is in the generated sources of the `camel-endpointdsl` ([here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/e526a3da26c58f6109a44e96c279afc3523c2f48/core/camel-endpointdsl/src/generated/java/org/apache/camel/builder/endpoint/dsl/MailEndpointBuilderFactory.java)).

Is there any additional step I need to take to have my component working with the endpoint DSL or do I have to code the Builder myself?

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported - only the out of the box components are in the camel-endpointdsl. There is a JIRA ticket about adding support for 3rd party, but its not a high priority at this moment.

Comment: Thanks! I will code the builder myself then and I will keep updated to know if and when this option will be available.